How to inject a secret into a .NET 8 console app during the publish process?
I've developed a .NET 8 console application for distribution to a customer. This app requires a secret, but I want to ensure the secret remains confidential. I prefer not to store the secret in a file or hardcode it into the application, as I don't want it to be exposed in version control (secrets should never be committed to git). Instead, I need the secret to be injected into the application during the publishing process. The goal is for the application to have access to the secret at runtime without having it stored in plain text. How can I achieve that? I tried to look for a way to set the environment variables in the publish profiles but no luck so far. Any help highly appreciated

Leave it up to the client so their secret is isolated to their machine.

The thing is that the client is the one who should not know the secret.

One way to do it is to store secret in KeyVault - and fetch data using SecretClient from Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets
Code Sample:
var client = new SecretClient(
    new Uri("KeyVault_Uri_Here"),
    new ClientCertificateCredential("KeyVaultTenantId", "KeyVaultClientId", certificate));

var secret = client.GetSecret("secret-key", CancelationToken.None);

This example is using certificate to access the KV, but there are other ways.
You can find a lot of other examples.
